# How does one properly simplify a coq goal with a previous lemma?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, coq-tactic

Why doesn't the last line of my proof shed a successor instead of adding one.
Note: i'm doing these excercises outside of a classroom setting and don't condone people using it to cheat on hw, I just don't know where else to ask it.
From the tactics chapter in Pierce.

```
Theorem plus_n_n_injective : forall n m,
     n + n = m + m ->
     n = m.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n as [| n'].
  intros.
  simpl in H.
  destruct m.
  reflexivity.
  discriminate.
  intros.
  rewrite <- plus_n_Sm in H.
  destruct m.
  discriminate.
  rewrite <- plus_n_Sm in H.
  apply S_injective in H.
  simpl in H.
  apply S_injective in H.
  apply S_injective.
```

where these auxiliary lemmas are used

```
Theorem S_injective : forall (n m : nat),
  S n = S m ->
  n = m.
Proof.
  intros n m H1.
  assert (H2: n = pred (S n)). { reflexivity. }
  rewrite H2. rewrite H1. reflexivity.
Qed.
Theorem plus_n_Sm : forall n m : nat,
    S (n + m) = n + (S m).
Proof.
  intros n m. induction n as [| n' IHn'].
  simpl.
  reflexivity.
  simpl.
  rewrite -> IHn'.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Comment: any additional simplifications/suggestions in the proof are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the statement of `S_injective`:

```
Theorem S_injective : forall (n m : nat),
  S n = S m ->
  n = m.
```

you will see it says that to prove `n = m` it is enough to prove `S n = S m`.
Before you apply it, you have to prove `S n' = S m`, and then you say you only need to prove `S (S n') = S (S m)`. It's because `apply` in the goal is doing some backward thinking.

What you want instead is being able to say `n = m -> S n = S m`. You can prove the lemma by hand like you did, or you can use the `f_equal` tactic which works in general to prove `f n = f m` from `n = m` for any `f` (roughly).